# Help in interpreting 2 scatter graphs

Tags: analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I have 2 scatter graphs here. One showing benign records and other showing DDoS records. They both plot against the average size of backward packets and the average size of forward packets.

[image]

There appears to be no linear relationship between the two variables. However, i believe the scatter plots slightly resemble the y= 1/x graph where x>0 and y>0. My issue however is further describing the trend. How can i describe the differences in a better way?

Comment: When you account for the smaller number of data points, the two graphs actually look pretty similar *except* for scale. Try plotting them with the same scale and I think you'll see that the benign graph is pretty constant to 500, but the ddos graph is only constant to roughly 225. That's the difference I'd focus on.

Comment: @BarryCarter I indeed noticed that just before i saw your comment. Also both records have 100k records, so although it appears that DDoS has less, there is actually an equal amount of points.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have said "distinct" points.